# Multiple iFrames enlarges on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface, iframe

What am looking for is to have multiple iFrames (or something similar) on a page, any of which when hovered over enlarges in size. By default, they should only show part of the page.For example, most of the iFrames will have some charts or graphs. I was wondering if there was a way for me to only see the chart/graph and additionally when hovered-over the iFrame can expand in width and height. Would highly appreciate if anyone can provide any recommendation/pointers/code snippets about the same revolving around jsp/jquery/java script/css or something related. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery -

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#frame-1").mouseover(function() {
            $(this).attr({width: 800, 
                          height: 500});
            }).mouseleave(function() {
                $(this).attr({width: 300, 
                              height: 400});
                });
            });
```

w/ HTML -

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Frame Enlargementationing</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#frame-1").mouseover(function() {
                $(this).attr({width: 800, 
                              height: 500});
                }).mouseleave(function() {
                    $(this).attr({width: 300, 
                                  height: 400});
                    });
                });
    </script>
</head>
</html>
<body>

<h1>Hover:</h1>
<iframe id="frame-1" src="http://jquery.com/" width="300" height="400"></iframe>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, and I'd suggest changing the `z-index` of the frame when you hover over it (to something higher than everything else on the page).

Comment: +1 for your suggestions. They were very helpful. However what i really need is to be able to see part of the HTML page and on hover it can expand as it is doing right now. For example, most of the iFrames will have some charts or graphs. I was wondering if there was a way for me to only see the chart/graph by default and additionally when hovered the iFrame can expand in width and height. I would highly appreciate if there are recommendations around that.

Comment: Not really understanding what you're trying to do. =/.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this trick,

CSS

```
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

div.hover {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

html

```
<div>
    <iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('div').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover');
},
function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/GBEex/)

Comment: This is good and for multiple iFrames i can give them separate id's and enlarge width/height based on that id. However, i had to edit the question a little here.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a CSS psuedo hover class that makes the iframe bigger.

For example:

```
iframe { 
width: 500px;
height: 700px;
}

iframe:hover {
width: 700px;
height: 900px;
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if this will work with iframes... but it's worth a try!

Comment: I just updated my answer... It did say "hover" and changed it to "active".

Comment: I think "hover" is actually the one he wants

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However, i had to edit the question a little.